# Невозможно использовать переменную как строку

Tags: golang

Пишу бота, и столкнулся с проблемой вывода данных.
Получаю такую ошибку:

Cannot use t (type time.Time) as type string in argument to tgbotapi.NewMessage

```
if Text == "time" {

    t := time.Now()

    msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(ChatID,t)

    bot.Send(msg)

}
```

При попытке вывести только время, получаю:

Cannot use h (type int) as type string in argument to tgbotapi.NewMessage

```
    t := time.Now()

    h,_ := fmt.Printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", t.Hour(), t.Minute(), t.Second())

    msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(ChatID,h)
```

Comment: Очевидно, нужно использовать именно строку. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119748/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведите переменную `t` к типу строки, до того, как вызываете `tgbotapi.NewMessage`.

Comment: Получаю ошибку, когда вывожу только время, отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(ChatID,t.Format("HH:mm:ss"))